# Devices with AC to DC inverters given a DC current

Tags: ac, dc

This is mainly a question to suffice my curiosity, but if I gave a device that has a plug for AC current (like a wall socket) but gave it DC current instead, what would happen??

Comment: Different circuits will behave differently. There may be no one answer fits all devices. For example, if the supply first encounters a transformer, then nothing will happen other than the transformer heating up.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the device.

In our days, most devices uses a switching power supply and in that regard, it will work. (computer, display, and other consumer electronics most likely).

If the device uses and old-school transformer, it won't work.

Passive devices most likely will work like a toaster, but their lifetime will be reduced due to more arcing in the switch in DC.

For other types of devices, it depends whether the circuit needs an alternating power input to operate, which often can be guessed looking at the circuit.

All this given that the RMS voltage is equivalent.